# Netgear X6S R7900P - Multicast

Tags: wireless-networking, multicast

have a Netgear X6S R7900P set up as a Wireless AP which is connected to a Apple Airport Extreme. I ran into an issue where a multicast sent from one of the computers connected to the Apple Airport Extreme is not seen by the wireless clients on the Netgear X6S. I tried switching the wireless client to connect to Airport and they were able to successfully receive the multicast.

So, this seems to be a bug in the Netgear firmware unless I am doing something wrong. I looked through the settings in Netgear Genie but could not find anything related to the Multicasts (at least in the Wireless AP mode).

Are there any workarounds/fixes for this? Also looked at other open source firmware but does not look like any of them support the X6S.

Thanks,

Comment: Does your client device join the multicast group (using IGMP/MLD) upon connecting?

Comment: @grawity, I am using two Mac clients to test. On the one connected to Airport I am using 'ping 239.x.x.x' and using tcpdump on the Netgear Wifi client to look for the multicasts. This works fine when the Wifi client is connected to Airport but does not see anything when connected to Netgear.

Comment: That sounds like the client does absolutely nothing to subscribe to the multicasts. (Unlike broadcasts, they're _meant_ to only be received by subscribed clients.) Try to ping 224.0.0.251, all Macs are subscribed to that one.

Comment: @grawity, tried 224.0.0.251 and I am able to see that on the Netgear Wifi. So why would 239.x.x.x work on the Airport Wifi and not the Netgear Wifi?